# Getting assert_select to show me what an element actually was

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have the following test:

```
test "users title when logged out" do
  get users_path
  assert_select "title", 'Correct title"
end
```

If we assume that users_path returns a page with `<title>Wrong title</title>`, then I get the following output:

```
FAIL["test_users_title_when_logged_out", SiteLayoutTest, 1.0830602300120518]
 test_users_title_when_logged_out#SiteLayoutTest (1.08s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "title", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

I would like to replace the assert_select with something like `assert_equal "Correct title", page.title` so that the test failure message actually *shows me what the page's title is*, which would make tracing the problem much easier! (Naturally, the page shows the correct title in development mode…)

However, page.title does not seem to be available, and my efforts at searching are only turning up stuff like "you can do it with Capybara", which is a bit bulky for this purpose!

Is there a way to write this test so that it shows something like `Expected page title to be "Correct title" but got "Wrong title"` instead? [**Edit for clarity:** "Wrong title" is the title in the returned page, not a literal string — that is, I need the error to tell me what was actually returned.]

Comment: Did you try `assert_select "title", 'Correct title", 'Expected page title to be "Correct title" but got "Wrong title"'` ?

Comment: Not sure how that helps, if I'm putting "Wrong title" as a literal string — I want it to show the actual title that's in the page that `get users_path` returns…

Comment: That helps when you want to see a fixed failure message all the time. But I got now, what you are trying to achieve. You are looking for Rspec like output, but I have no idea in minitest. But looks like you need to monkey patch to override the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is `assert_equal 'Correct title', css_select('title').first.content`.

This gives the more helpful failure message

```
FAIL["test_users_title_when_logged_out", SiteLayoutTest, 1.0830602300120518]
 test_users_title_when_logged_out#SiteLayoutTest (1.08s)
Expected: "Correct title"
  Actual: "Wrong title"
```

(though I suspect it may be better style to revert to the original assert_select once I've found the problem!)